# Run CURL GET commands in Azure Pipeline Task

Tags: rest, curl, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-pipelines-tasks

I am looking to run some CURL commands (GET mainly) in an Azure Pipeline Task to list/download some artifacts from a few sources. Would appreciate some help with any examples of how I can achieve this through a Pipeline Task using CURL, Powershell, Windows Command or any other appropriate method.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task. For a YAML pipeline, this would look like

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: Curl Example
  inputs:
    script: 'curl google.com'
```

For a "Classic UI" pipeline, it would look like

[image]

Note that for either of these options you must be using a Linux build agent. If you are using a Windows build agent, you should use `Invoke-WebRequest`.

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT, thanks for the response which is excellent. 

However, having set up the Powershell Task in Azure Pipelines, I'm still having an issue when attempting to download a Maven package (which was not originally created in Azure DevOps but has been imported into Azure Artifacts from an external project) from my feed. It appears to fail on the authentication method used in my Invoke-WebRequest command.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Is `curl` command even available in a pipeline?

Answer (score 3):

`curl` in PowerShell uses [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1). From PowerShell 3.03.0 and above, we could use `Invoke-WebRequest`, which is equivalent to `curl`. You could refer to this [doc](https://discoposse.com/2012/06/30/powershell-invoke-restmethod-putting-the-curl-in-your-shell/) for more details

Sample script in the power shell

```
 Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://www.educative.io/
```

In addition, in the Azure DevOps Artifacts, the URL contain special characters, we need use "" contain it. Such as

```
https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_packaging?_a=feed+"&"+feed={feed name}
```